# Heroku Node app push - getting error out of no where

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have been working on this for some time without an issue. I made one small change, which had nothing to do with the dependencies or packages of the app - it was just in a controller method. When I go to push to heroku, I'm getting this error. I also tried changing branches, but the error persists.

I don't even know what Sharp is, but it seems to be causing the issue, or maybe it's a false alarm but it's showing the issue as sharp but it's something else?

(Before someone makes the suggestion - I replaced the name of my app with 'example'. No, it's not like that in the actual script.)

```
Total 0 (delta 0),

 reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.13.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.12.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > sharp@0.21.3 install /tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/node_modules/node-paperclip-resize-image/node_modules/sharp
remote:        > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
remote:        
remote:        info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.0/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/node_modules/node-paperclip-resize-image/node_modules/sharp/build'
remote:          TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
remote:        In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:20: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                            ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                             ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:39: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                               ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:56: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                                ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:60: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                                    ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:79:29: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                     ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:79:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                      ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:79:48: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                        ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:79:65: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                                         ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:80:38: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                              ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:80:55: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                               ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:80:57: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                                 ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:80:74: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                                                                                  ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:48: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                        ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:65: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                         ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:67: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                           ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:84: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                                            ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:37: warning: variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                             ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:81:90: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
remote:           template<typename T> v8::Local<T> AttrAs(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                                                  ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:37: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                             ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                              ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:56: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                                 ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:26: warning: variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                  ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:79: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                                       ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:87:37: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, int attr) {
remote:                                             ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:87:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, int attr) {
remote:                                                              ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:87:56: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, int attr) {
remote:                                                                ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:87:61: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, int attr) {
remote:                                                                     ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:84:26: warning: variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                  ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:87:71: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
remote:           template<typename T> T AttrTo(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, int attr) {
remote:                                                                               ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:9: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                 ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                  ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:28: error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                    ^~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:28: note: suggested alternative: ‘ino_t’
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                    ^~~~~
remote:                                    ino_t
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:70: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                                                              ^
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:71: error: ‘buffersToPersist’ was not declared in this scope
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.h:93:87: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist);
remote:                                                                                               ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:34:20: error: redefinition of ‘bool sharp::HasAttr’
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                            ^~~~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
remote:        ../src/common.h:78:8: note: ‘bool sharp::HasAttr’ previously defined here
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                ^~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:34:20: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                            ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:34:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                             ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:34:39: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                               ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:34:56: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:37:29: error: redefinition of ‘std::string sharp::AttrAsStr’
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                     ^~~~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
remote:        ../src/common.h:79:15: note: ‘std::string sharp::AttrAsStr’ previously declared here
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                       ^~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:37:29: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                     ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:37:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                      ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:37:48: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                        ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:37:65: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           std::string AttrAsStr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                         ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:40:38: error: redefinition of ‘std::vector<double> sharp::AttrAsRgba’
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                              ^~~~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
remote:        ../src/common.h:80:23: note: ‘std::vector<double> sharp::AttrAsRgba’ previously declared here
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
remote:                               ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:40:38: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                              ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:40:55: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                               ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:40:57: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                 ^~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:40:74: error: expected primary-expression before ‘attr’
remote:           std::vector<double> AttrAsRgba(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr) {
remote:                                                                                  ^~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:9: error: redefinition of ‘sharp::InputDescriptor* sharp::CreateInputDescriptor’
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                 ^~~~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
remote:        ../src/common.h:92:20: note: ‘sharp::InputDescriptor* sharp::CreateInputDescriptor’ previously defined here
remote:           InputDescriptor* CreateInputDescriptor(
remote:                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:9: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                 ^~~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                                  ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:28: error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                                    ^~~~~
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:28: note: suggested alternative: ‘ino_t’
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                                    ^~~~~
remote:                                    ino_t
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:70: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                                                                              ^
remote:        ../src/common.cc:51:71: error: ‘buffersToPersist’ was not declared in this scope
remote:             v8::Handle<v8::Object> input, std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Object>> &buffersToPersist
remote:                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        sharp.target.mk:136: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/node_modules/node-paperclip-resize-image/node_modules/sharp/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_739dd517149d4391a47cfc8a1f1dd282/node_modules/node-paperclip-resize-image/node_modules/sharp
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.dLvYO/_logs/2019-10-28T14_55_48_980Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to example.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/example.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/example.git'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was correct - the issue was actually a discrepancy with Sharp and the version of Node I was using (12.xx.xx). I downgraded to 10.16.0 and it worked fine. I hope this saves someone else time :/

Comment: This works really well! Was struggling with Heroku but this fixed it for me!Thanks!